# Grabbing quick drinks

Tags: wordplay

> I asked ________ friend:
>   - ________ interest you in a drink?
>   - Sure. I want a ________.
>   - Alright, let's go. I'll just grab ________.

Fill the blanks, two words per line. What do the answers have in common?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The word pairs sound like they are

> homophones.

Giving the conversation:

> I asked *my Thai* friend:
>  *Might I* interest you in a drink?
>  Sure. I want a *Mai Tai*.
>  Alright, let's go. I'll just grab *my tie*.

Answer (score 1):

I missed the "Two words" requirement but I thought I post my answer anyway

They are all

> Single character representative words: ARTC

'C' as

> the unit for Cup, may be a bit of a stretch

so an alternative in the US is

> ART¼ where Quarter is $.25 and a bit small for any amount of Tea.

Comment: I don't see how your second letter fits. That seems kinda ungrammatical.